# Error CORS Spring + Angular 5 + Jasperreport

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jasper-reports

That is my class Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/adiantamento-api/adiantamento")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class RelatorioController {
     .....
   }
```

And that is my method the generate a report, the is inside RelatorioController

```
@RequestMapping(path="gerar-relatorio/", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    public void gerarRelatorio(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        try {



            String nomeRelatorio = "RelAdvertenciaDB";//JsonUtils.getProperty(parametros, "nome_relatorio", "x", String.class);
            Map<String, Object> reportParameters = new HashMap<>();

            DatabaseContextHolder.set(DatabaseEnvironment.CICLOCAIRU);


            reportParameters.put("CODIGO", 880);            
            InputStream reportStream = new  ClassPathResource("relatorios/" + nomeRelatorio + ".jrxml").getInputStream();


            JasperReport jasper =  JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportStream);
            JRSaver.saveObject(jasper, "report.jasper");

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, reportParameters, jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());

            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();                       

            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(
              new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("src\\main\\resources\\relatorios\\gerados\\"+nomeRelatorio+".pdf"));

            SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig
              = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
            reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
            reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);

            SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig
              = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
            exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("JETERSON");             

            exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
            exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);

            exporter.exportReport();


            File file = new File("src\\main\\resources\\relatorios\\gerados\\"+nomeRelatorio+".pdf");
            try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()){
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+nomeRelatorio+".pdf");
                IOUtils.copy(is, out);
                out.flush();
            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

My Cors Filter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfigCors extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is a important, but this is my Class of Authentication

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    // EXPIRATION_TIME = 10 dias
    static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 860_000_000;
    static final String SECRET = "MySecret";
    static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
    static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, String username) {
        String JWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();

        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", HEADER_STRING);
    }

    static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (token != null) {
            // faz parse do token
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The Project have many controllers that the client angular do requests, but only my class RelatorioController throw error cors, when generate a `report Jasper` i receive the error in browser `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

I suspect that is because of `jasper reposrts` it spite of make no sense 
If i comment all lines codes responsibility for generate report, a request works

**Edit**: That is my angular call

```
emitirAdvertencia(parametros: Object): any {
        parametros['dbenv'] = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getDbenv();
        parametros['usuario'] = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getUser().codigoUsuario;
        parametros['nome_relatorio'] = 'RelAdvertenciaDB';
        var httpOptions = {

            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                'Authorization': this.localStorage.get('token'),
                // all others methods not need this
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }),
            responseType: 'blob' as 'blob',
        };        
        return this.http.get(ApplicationContext.URL + '/adiantamento/gerar-relatorio/', httpOptions)
            .map((res) => {
                return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the wildcard ('*') on the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not usable when the client provides credentials. When credentials are provided, the allowed origin needs to be specific.

So, you could try changing

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I modified it as suggested, but it still does not work, I edited and added in the question my angular code

Comment: I discovered. Precisa adicionar Cors em HttpServletResponse no meu controlador `response.addHeader (" Access-Control-Allow-Origin "," * ");`